# Using "c'mon guy" instead of "c'mon man"

Tags: word-choice

Is it possible to use *c'mon guy* instead of *c'mon man*?

Comment: No, it's not possible.  If you try to say it, your face will explode.

Comment: It depends if you're a Cali bro

Comment: I don't understand the closevotes. I found 95 instances of *"c'mon guy"* in Google Books - so it's not totally unknown, even if it's rare compared to *"c'mon man"*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just substitute *guy* for *man* in such idiomatic expressions. For example, we don't use *"Hey, guy!"* as a greeting - it's *"Hey, man!"*. And an *"all right guy"* is someone we approve of - if we're enthusiastically agreeing with someone we say *"All right, man!"*.

Some people might think *"Hey, c'mon guy!"* is a bit more distant/hostile than the far more common *"Hey, c'mon, man!"*, but I certainly wouldn't use *guy* there myself. If I was trying to talk down to the guy, I wouldn't want him thinking I didn't have a proper grasp of idiomatic language.

Answer (score -1):

You can say "c'mon guy" but depending on the region "guy" might be seen as somewhat derogatory. It could be a response to someone who you hold little respect for, where "c'mon man" would be something you say to a friend.